# [Redux-saga][EventChannel] When two events are triggered at the same time, I cannot intercept these events in the channel

Tags: reactjs, redux, twilio, redux-saga

When the typing indicator and the added message events are triggered at the same time, the channel does not catch these events.

```
const eventListener = (channel) => eventChannel((emit) => {
  const handler = (data) => {
    emit(data);
  };

  if (channel) {
    channel.on(ChannelEvents.MESSAGE_ADDED, (payload) => handler({
      type: ChannelEvents.MESSAGE_ADDED, payload,
    }));
    channel.on(ChannelEvents.TYPING_STARTED, (payload) => handler({
      type: ChannelEvents.TYPING_STARTED, payload,
    }));
    channel.on(ChannelEvents.TYPING_ENDED, (payload) => handler({
      type: ChannelEvents.TYPING_ENDED, payload,
    }));
    channel.on(ChannelEvents.DISCONNECT, () => {
      emit(END);
    });
  }

  return () => { };
});

 const channel = yield call(eventListener, systemChannel);

  while (true) {
    const { payload, type } = yield take(channel);
...
```

I tried to use take Every, but takeEvery doesn't have a queue. How to fix this without creating a own queue?

Comment: Do you find that one of the events is executed, just not both of them? Is that because `yield take(channel)` is blocking? What happens when you use `takeEvery`? That seems to be the right choice here as it forks multiple tasks to be run concurrently.

Comment: If I emit some event, when channel is blocking due to take, I will miss this event. I need to have a sequence for events, I see that I can implement only own order

Comment: Yeah, so that's why `takeEvery` should work as it will fork and not block. So what went wrong with `takeEvery`?